Let L = {1^s| such that there exist s consecutive 1s in the (decimal) expansion of π}. Is the language L Turing-decidable?
Let $L = \{1^s|$ such that there exist $s$ consecutive 1s in the (decimal) expansion of $\pi\}$.
Is the language $L$ Turing-decidable?
At first glance it seems like it would not be Turing-decidable because $\pi$ is infinite. Is this a correct hunch? If so how do I express this formally. If not can someone help me understand why. Thanks.
